# Mobile App Development - HTML5 LocalStorage versus SessionStorage versus Cookies

Tags: web-applications, mobile, security, jquery-mobile

We are developing a mobile web application on the jQuery Mobile platform that requires a user to provide their username and password.

Rather than asking the user to re-enter their details each time we want to only ask them once for their username and password and then prompt them to enter a pin.

We will encrypt this pin and encrypt a user identifier string and save both either in LocalStorage or Cookie.

When the user visits the application for a second time we will test if a user identifier can be found and if so prompt them to enter a pin.

Once the pin is entered we will securely (SSL) pass the pin and the user identifier to be decrytped and validated on the server.

I've read in a few places that we should use Cookies instead of LocalStorage (from a security point of view). Would you concur with this and can cookies be used across most smart-phones?

We also need to ensure that the user is required to re-enter their pin each time they close the browser or browse to another page or exceed 30 minutes of inactivity.

To manage this I was thinking of storing a value in SessionStorage as I have read that this is more secure than LocalStorage and expires when the browser is closed. Alternatively we could use Cookies again.

Security is a key concern so I'd be intersted to hear any tips and/or alternative approaches you may have.

Many thanks in advance...

Comment: I read the conversation in the answer you selected. Storing a PIN even if hashed is as "bad" as storing a password because they can be unhashed - but I understand where you're coming from : However the same issue arises even if you only sending the pin to the server. The standard practice is to add salt on the server side to any hash that has been received, hash that and then store the result. Later at each subsequent logon compare received hash to what you've stored with an offset allowing for the length of the hashed salt which of course only you know. Thus avoiding any direct storage.

Comment: How do you unhash it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If security is your chief concern, I would not recommend using cookies since they are sent with every request to the server, which could potentially be intercepted by anyone sniffing that traffic over the network.  Performance-wise, using cookies also increases the amount of data going back and forth between server and client.

For your purposes I would choose `sessionStorage` if you want your data to be persistent only for the life of the browser session, including as well a timestamp that you can test for session expiration.  Data in `sessionStorage` and `localStorage` stays only on the client and is never sent to the server.

Comment: Thanks for the response, do you think it is acceptable to store the pin and user identifier (both encrypted) on LocalStorage?

Comment: If you're decrypting and validating the pin on the server, and they must reenter the pin if they browse to another page, then it would be best if you stored a timestamp in `sessionStorage` that would only be checked on that page. The timestamp would have a sliding expiration, meaning that it would be updated to the new current time if it had not yet reached the 30 minute expiration.

Comment: The user id is fine to store in `localStorage` as long as it does not include any PII (personally identifiable info), even if it's encrypted, but I would personally never store a pin/password/passphrase, encrypted or not, anywhere outside the server, and even on the server I wouldn't store it in clear text or even in any decryptable form, but instead convert the pin to a hash with a one-way algorithm, preferably with salt, and whenever the user enters their pin, convert it to hash and compare it to the hash stored on the server.

Comment: Thanks, that's excellent advice. So we would store a non personally identifiable hash in LocalStorage and store the PIN on the server. When the user enters the pin we would send it along with the hash in LocalStorage and ensure both validate

Comment: I presume sessionStorage applies across a domain rather than a single web page? So it would only be if the user browsed to another domain that they would be asked for a pin (on return to the application). Thanks for all the help

Comment: `sessionStorage` is saved by scheme/protocol, hostname, and port, so stored data is only accessible when all three match.

No thanks necessary, but voting up and accepting answer wouldn't hurt. ;)